A warp execute its instructions on a contiguous set of cores and registers during any given cycle?
I got the following questions regarding the mapping between cuda cores, register file, and threads of warp.

Threads in a warp are allocated contiguous set of registers in the register file. Registers maintains a logical offset. For instance:

Thread 0 : reg0, reg1, reg2
Thread 1 : reg3, reg4, reg5
Thread 2 : reg6, reg7, reg8

2.During any given cycle, instructions of a warp run on a contiguous set of cores.
Thread 0's instruction : core0
Thread 1's instruction : core1
Thread 2's instruction : core2

The above is necessary to simplify the dispatching logic, allowing the dispatch units to be small?
Any hint or answer is appreciated. Thank you!

Register allocation and access has been reverse-engineered for specific architectures, see for example Zhe Jia et.al. Dissecting the NVidia Turing T4 GPU via Microbenchmarking. section 3.5.

Note that CUDA cores are an abstraction. In practice, threads are coalesced in warps of 32 threads. In SASS, instructions operates on SIMD register where each lane represent a CUDA thread. As a result, we can clearly conclude that the register allocation is not done at a thread level. In fact, there is no reason for the allocation to change from one block to another since it is done statically (and has to be so to generate a SASS code). Thus, AFAIK it is done at a kernel level and registers are SIMD ones with >=8 physical lanes (for 32-bit operations)

Also if you look at things like the Volta Whitepaper figure 5, a single processing block runs 32 threads per clock in its dispatcher but has only 16 float "cores". With fewer cores than threads, the dispatcher wouldn't have much room to do dynamic thread-core allocation anyway. The exact behavior is not documented AFAIK but it seems reasonable that it simply dispatches two half-warps over two clock cycles to all cores

@Homer512 I benchmarked arithmetic instructions (FMA/MUL/ADD) on my Nvidia 1660S GPU (Turing) and the result was 2 cycles of throughput which tends to confirm the "two half-warps over two clock cycles to all cores". The latency was 4 cycles. See a discussion about that here here. On older architectures, the latency was significantly higher and the throughput was AFAIK 4 (I read many years ago that they was scheduling warps 8 thread at a time at the hardware level).

@JérômeRichard Yes, 8 "cores" using 4 cycles with 24 cycles latency in CUDA-1.0 https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/questin-regarding-latency/18452/6

@Homer512 Thanks for the confirmation. On newer architectures (starting from Ampere), I suspect the throughput of float FMA/ADD/MUL is now 1 warp (i.e. 32 threads) since fma_flop/frequency/sm_count/2 ~= 128 (based on Wikipedia) and there are still apparently 4 slices per SM (based on Nvidia docs) so 32 flops/slice/cycle that is 1 warp/slice/cycle (for these math instructions). However, Nvidia strangely still print 16 float "cores" in the architecture figures... Did I missed something? Do you know whether this is 16 or 32 on newer arch?

@JérômeRichard According to the tuning guide, 8.6 devices have twice the FP32 throughput compared to 8.0. 8.0 is also called Ampere (e.g. A100) and is the one listed in the Ampere whitepaper. The whitepaper shows 64 FP32 cores per SM, 16 per processing block. So I guess with Ampere we have to be really careful which cuda version it is, specifically.
